# Else if statement executes despite first condition is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a patch of code that is intended to perform a search across a sheet then assign a variable if found.

Here's the code:

```
  for(i=0;i<values.length; i++)
      {
        rowvalue = values[i];        
        for (j=l=1;j<rowvalue.length; j++) {
             colvalue = rowvalue[j];             
             colvalue1 = colvalue.toString();             
             if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1
                && rowvalue[j+5] == "") {
                rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;               
                var itemcode = 9;
      }
    else if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1) {
                rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;               
                var itemcode = 9;
                }
```

When executed, it will always return the value that met the 2nd condition(else if), despite the first condition was met. If I remove the else if statements, then I will get the correct return value.

As far as I know, once if statement was fulfilled, it's supposed to skip else or else if. But for some reason this wasn't the case in my situation. I'm not sure if I'm using the function properly or I'm misunderstanding on how the function work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the same function this way:

```
if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1 ) 
{
  if (rowvalue[j+5] == "")
  {
    rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;
    var itemcode = 9;
  }else{
    rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;               
    var itemcode = 9;
  }
}
```

Comment: This method did return the value I sought for. Thank you! But I don't understand why this works but my method doesn't.

Comment: Probably because your else if statement which doesn't include the condition `rowvalue[j+5] == ""` always holds true irrespective of the `rowvalue` at position j+5 being null or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code correctly it becomes rather obvious where it goes wrong

Your code indented.

```
    for(i=0;i<values.length; i++)
    {
        rowvalue = values[i];        
        for (j=l=1;j<rowvalue.length; j++) 
        {
            colvalue = rowvalue[j];             
            colvalue1 = colvalue.toString();             
            if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1 && rowvalue[j+5] == "") 
            {
                 rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;
                 var itemcode = 9;
                 else if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1) 
                 {
                     rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;               
                     var itemcode = 9;

                 }
```

What you probably meant was to as below, please note the "Added missing closing curly bracket"

```
for(i=0;i<values.length; i++)
{
    rowvalue = values[i];        
    for (j=l=1;j<rowvalue.length; j++) 
    {
        colvalue = rowvalue[j];             
        colvalue1 = colvalue.toString();             
        if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1 && rowvalue[j+5] == "") 
        {
             rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;
             var itemcode = 9;
        } // Added missing closing curly bracket
        else if(colvalue1.indexOf("search1")>-1 && colvalue1.indexOf("search2")==-1) 
        {
            rowp = i+1, colp = j+1;               
            var itemcode = 9;

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I apologize as the missing bracket was a mistake while copying the code to the post. I double checked and tried to run the code and it still executed else if despite the if condition was met.

Answer (score 0):

single closing curly brace before the else statement should resolve the issue.